# Is the zero a valid kernel?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, kernel-trick

It seems to me that if $c\geq0$ then $k(x,y)=c$ is a valid kernel since no rules are broken.

However, one of the rules of constructing a kernel disagrees with this. The rule is $k(x,y)=ck'(x,y)$, where it must be true that $c>0$ (this rule is taken from Bishop, Pattern Recognition And Machine Learning). Why can't $c$ be 0? The zero matrix is symmetric and positive semidefinite, so isn't it true that $k(x,y)=0$ should be a valid kernel?

Comment: To what "rules" do you refer?  This matters, because perhaps your rules differ from those of other people.  Some, for instance, require that a kernel integrate to unity.  None of your examples has this property.

Comment: I'm also mildly confused, since the constant zero is a valid kernel by [Mercer's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercer%27s_theorem#Mercer's_condition), yet zero is not a proper inner product since it does not meet the requirement that `<x, x>` is greater than zero.

Answer (score 1):

$k(x, y) = 0$ is a positive semidefinite kernel, as is easy to check from the definition (as you've done). It's not, however, a very useful kernel.

Bishop's list of the ways to construct one kernel from another is not an exhaustive list, as you've discovered. They're not necessary for being a kernel; they're just a set of conditions where you know how to construct one kernel from another. His rule would still be valid if he replaced the condition $c > 0$ with $c \ge 0$, but I suppose he didn't bother because the difference can only get you the zero kernel, which is useless anyway.